# Parametrize android package and ios bundle id with EAS on Bare workflow

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm currently working on a expo project and I had the bundle configuration parametrized with environment variables declared on `eas.json` and used on `app.config.ts`.

Some like this

eas.json

```json
{
    "cli": {
        "version": ">= 0.48.2"
    },
    "build": {
        "develop": {
            "distribution": "store",
            "env": {
                "ENVIRONMENT": "develop"
            },
            "releaseChannel": "dev-v1"
        },
        "production": {
            "releaseChannel": "prod-v1",
            "env": {
                "ENVIRONMENT": "production"
            },
            "distribution": "store"
        }
}
```

app.config.ts

```js
//removed a lot of not relevant code
 ios: {
            supportsTablet: true,
            bundleIdentifier: getBundleId(), // returns correct bundle id based on ENVIRONMENT variable.
            buildNumber: '1.0.4',
        },
 android: {
            adaptiveIcon: {
                foregroundImage: './assets/adaptive-icon.png',
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            },
            package: getBundleId(), // same of ios BundleIdentifier
            versionCode: 104,
        },
```

But now, for some requirements I have to eject the project into the [bare workflow](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/exploring-bare-workflow/), and because of that I'm getting the follow message when I want to generate a new build with eas (with `eas build -p=ios --profile=production`)

> Specifying "ios.bundleIdentifier" in app.config.ts is deprecated for bare workflow projects.
> EAS Build depends only on the value in the native code. Please remove the deprecated configuration.

Does exist any way to keep bundleIdentifier, packageId and also the app schema parametrized by environment after eject?